# "npm run build:css " can not work, while it is ok when I run the script self

Tags: javascript, json, npm-run

I am doing a program, I meet some question when I use the npm script with Mac system;
 I have already install the node-sass globally, the package.json file is as follows: [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI4gW.png)
it is not work when I run "npm run build:css",while the error the system tell me is as the follow picture:
[the err discription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8qsg.jpg)
**but** I can run the commend `node-sass ./src/scss/pages/index.scss ./static/css/index.css` successfully in the terminal and if I add another line like `"create":"touch sun.js"` to package.json, it works well when I run `npm run create`;

I am confused, I will be grateful if someone can give some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the `node-sass` module that's installed *locally* in the working directory is missing dependencies, or is otherwise partially configured. Try running `npm install` to restore any missing dependencies.

The reason `node-sass` runs successfully in the terminal might be because it's running from a different (probably global) installation. Run `which node-sass` to find the location of the running executable..

Comment: I have installed node-sass locally and globally,and  I didn't miss the dependencies, I have solved this problem by uninstalling node-sass locally , and it works well now; I think maybe the local node-sass misleading the `npm run` command ; so the global `node-sass` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use node-sass? 
Here is my script, try this:

```
"scripts": {
    "sass": "sass --sourcemap=none --watch resources/assets/sass:public/assets/css"
  }
```

If you need the source map, just delete the `--sourcemap=none` part, and of course, change the source and destination path.

Comment: I didn't use sass because sass need the environment with ruby, not all my partners have installed it,  so I choose node-sass